# How to merge multiple objects from different models into one object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, hashmap

I want to know if there is an elegant way to merge multiple records from different Models into one new object ?

The case is to build a 'stream' or 'feed' of the app content, like in Facebook.

In detail, each record have multiple and different columns. This is the Models and columns  :

- Product [name, price]
- Post [tagline, image]
- Member [name, username, profilepic]
- Selection [name, tagline]

The code I tried :

```
@new_object = @product = Product.find(n) + @post = Product.find(n) + @member = Member.find(n) + @selection = Selection.find(n)
```

But this is not working because of the differences of fields. I think we have to map into a Hash ?

This is how I will use the final object :

```
@new_object.each do |stream|
  stream.foo
  stream.bar
end
```

So, the goal : take each record and display the content with .each
Luxury : have the oportunity to sort randomly the results.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a PORO (plain old ruby object) to represent the combined object so something like:

```
class Stream 
  attr_accessor :product, :post, :member, :selection

  def initialize(attrs)
    assign_attributes(attrs)
  end
end
```

Then just [initialize](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/objinitialization.html) and create as many `stream` objects as you need using `Stream.new(attrs)`. You can create an array of `stream` objects and loop through them to render or show multiple `stream` data.

For sorting an array of objects by its attributes you can use

`objects.sort_by {|obj| obj.attribute}`